# Problem using signInWithEmailAndPassword method form Firebase 9 in Nuxt Vue

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

I'm working on this problem for a few days and I don't know how to solve it.

This is my nuxt login page and I use the new Firebase 9 auth pack to authenticate a user.
I call the signInWithEmailAndPassword method to authenticate.
When I try it with the correct credentials I never get into the first then() of the Promise:

```js
.then((userCredential) => {
          alert(userCredential)
          this.$store.commit('setUser', userCredential.user)
        })
```

But when I type in the incorrect credentials, I always get the correct error (in the catch) and the second then() is always executed.

I don't understand why I can't log in.

Can anyone help me?

Sorry for the bad English.

My login page: (pages/index.vue)

```html
<template>
  <v-container fluid fill-height>
    <v-layout align-center justify-center>
      <v-flex xs12 sm8 md4>
        <v-card class="elevation-12">
          <v-toolbar dark color="primary">
            <v-toolbar-title>Anmelden</v-toolbar-title>
          </v-toolbar>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-form
              id="login-form"
              ref="form"
              v-model="valid"
              lazy-validation
              @submit.prevent="emailLogin()"
            >
              <v-text-field
                v-model="formData.email"
                :rules="emailRules"
                name="email"
                label="E-Mail"
                counter
                required
              />

              <v-text-field
                v-model="formData.password"
                :append-icon="show ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
                :rules="passwordRules"
                :type="show ? 'text' : 'password'"
                name="password"
                label="Passwort"
                counter
                required
                @click:append="show = !show"
              />
            </v-form>
          </v-card-text>
          <v-snackbar
            v-model="snackbar"
            :timeout="timeout"
          >
            {{ text }}

            <template #action="{ attrs }">
              <v-btn
                color="yellow accent-2"
                text
                v-bind="attrs"
                @click="snackbar = false"
              >
                Schließen
              </v-btn>
            </template>
          </v-snackbar>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer />
            <v-btn
              type="submit"
              form="login-form"
              :disabled="!valid"
              block
              color="primary"
              class="mr-4"
            >
              Login
            </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { auth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from '@/plugins/firebase'
export default {
  data: () => ({
    show: false,
    valid: true,
    snackbar: '',
    timeout: 10000,
    text: '',
    formData: {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    },
    emailRules: [
      v => !!v || 'E-Mail ist verpflichtend',
      v => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || 'Keine gültige E-Mail-Adresse'
    ],
    passwordRules: [
      v => !!v || 'Passwort ist verpflichtend'
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    emailLogin () {
      signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, this.formData.email, this.formData.password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          alert(userCredential)
          this.$store.commit('setUser', userCredential.user)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          switch (error.code) {
            case 'auth/invalid-email':
              this.text = 'Die E-Mail-Adresse ist falsch'
              break
            case 'auth/user-disabled':
              this.text = 'Der User ist deaktiviert'
              break
            case 'auth/user-not-found':
              this.text = 'Kein Account gefunden'
              break
            case 'auth/wrong-password':
              this.text = 'Das Passwort ist falsch'
              break
            default:
              this.text = 'Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten: ' + error.message
              break
          }
          this.snackbar = true
        }).then(() => {
          this.formData.email = ''
          this.formData.password = ''
          this.$refs.form.resetValidation()
          this.$router.push('/post')
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My firebase setup file: (plugins/firbase.js) --> is registered in nuxt.config.js

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage'
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'key',
  authDomain: 'domain',
  projectId: 'project',
  storageBucket: 'bucket',
  messagingSenderId: 'message',
  appId: 'app',
  measurementId: 'measure'
}

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const auth = getAuth(app)
const fire = getFirestore(app)
const storage = getStorage(app)

export { auth, fire, storage, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut, onAuthStateChanged }
```

Comment: Hi, I've properly edited your question.